# R- Calculate rolling mean from values match a column across multiple columns

Tags: r, mean

Test Data

```
library(data.table)
data<-data.table(
Date= c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-05", "2018-01-06"),
Winner= c("A","D","B","A","C","A"),
Loser=c("B","C","A","C","B","C"),
wpointp=c("52","58","51","61","59","55"),
lpointp=c("48","42","49","39","41","45"))
```

I have a data table which lists the winners and losers of games, along with the percentage of points in the game that they won. I'd like to have an additional column which calculates the winners historical point percentage over the past games("wpoint.av"), whether they were a winner or a loser previously.

I know I can use the following code using zoo and rollapply to obtain a rolling mean of all the appearances the winner appears in the winner column, but I am unable to make it also count any times the winner has also appeared in the loser column:

```
data$wpointp<-as.numeric(data$wpointp)
data$lpointp<-as.numeric(data$lpointp)
data[,wpointp.av. := lag(rollapply(wpointp,mean,width=10000,align="right",partial=TRUE, fill=NA)),by="Winner"]
```

So rather than "wpointp.av" returning 52 in row 4, it should return 50.5 after averaging wpointp in row 1 and lpointp in row 3 - corresponding to A's two games. Is this something I can do with rollapply, or do I need to find a separate function?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think I understand, what exactly do you want to see in the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that the question is asking that for each row find the earlier rows having that row's winner as either a winner or loser.  Then from those rows take wpointp for those rows for which it is a winner and lpointp for those rows for which it is a loser and average all those numbers.

**1) sqldf** We first make wpointp and lpointp numeric and then left join the result to itself using the indicated `on` condition and produce the average shown using `avg`.

```
library(data.table)
library(sqldf)

data2 <- copy(data)
data2[, c("wpointp", "lpointp") := .(as.numeric(wpointp), as.numeric(lpointp))]

sqldf("select a.*, 
 avg((a.Winner = b.Winner)*b.wpointp + (a.Winner = b.Loser)*b.lpointp) 'wpoint.av',
 from data2 a
 left join data2 b
 on b.Date < a.Date and ((a.Winner = b.Winner) or (a.Winner = b.Loser))
 group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
        Date Winner Loser wpointp lpointp wpoint.av
1 2018-01-01      A     B      52      48        NA
2 2018-01-02      D     C      58      42        NA
3 2018-01-03      B     A      51      49      48.0
4 2018-01-04      A     C      61      39      50.5
5 2018-01-05      C     B      59      41      40.5
6 2018-01-06      A     C      55      45      54.0
```

**2)** This only uses data.table.  It might be slow although I added a few speedups since the initial version.

```
Mean <- function(i) {
  w <- data2$Winner[i]
  data2[1:.N < i & (Winner == w | Loser == w),
     mean((Winner == w) * wpointp + (Loser == w) * lpointp)]
}
data2 <- copy(data)
data2[, c("wpointp", "lpointp") := .(as.numeric(wpointp), as.numeric(lpointp))]

data2[, wpoint.av := sapply(.I, Mean)]
data2
```

giving:

```
         Date Winner Loser wpointp lpointp wpoint.av
1: 2018-01-01      A     B      52      48       NaN
2: 2018-01-02      D     C      58      42       NaN
3: 2018-01-03      B     A      51      49      48.0
4: 2018-01-04      A     C      61      39      50.5
5: 2018-01-05      C     B      59      41      40.5
6: 2018-01-06      A     C      55      45      54.0
```

**3) dplyr/tidyr** Convert the indicated columns to numeric, convert to long form, use cummean to calculate rolling mean, extract out the Winner rows and join them back to the original data.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
 mutate(wpointp = as.numeric(wpointp), lpointp = as.numeric(lpointp)) %>%
 pivot_longer(Winner:Loser) %>%
 group_by(value) %>%
 mutate(pointp.av = 
   lag(cummean((name=="Winner") * wpointp + (name=="Loser") * lpointp))) %>%
 ungroup %>%
 filter(name == "Winner") %>%
 select(Date, pointp.av) %>%
 right_join(data, by = "Date") %>%
 select(Date, Winner, Loser, wpointp, lpointp, pointp.av)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Date       Winner Loser wpointp lpointp pointp.av
  <chr>      <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <chr>       <dbl>
1 2018-01-01 A      B     52      48           NA  
2 2018-01-02 D      C     58      42           NA  
3 2018-01-03 B      A     51      49           48  
4 2018-01-04 A      C     61      39           50.5
5 2018-01-05 C      B     59      41           40.5
6 2018-01-06 A      C     55      45           54
```

**4)**   This uses only base R.   First convert to long form using reshape and sort it in Date order.  Them define a cumMean function and apply it by Winner.  At the end extract out the Winner rows.

```
varying <- list(c("Winner", "Loser"), c("wpointp", "lpointp"))
long <- reshape(data, dir = "long", varying = varying)
long <- long[order(long$Date), ]
cumMean <- function(x) c(NA, head(cumsum(x), -1)) / (seq_along(x) - 1)
long2 <- transform(long, av = ave(as.numeric(wpointp), Winner, FUN = cumMean))
subset(long2, time == 1)
```

giving:

```
         Date time Winner wpointp id   av
1: 2018-01-01    1      A      52  1   NA
2: 2018-01-02    1      D      58  2   NA
3: 2018-01-03    1      B      51  3 48.0
4: 2018-01-04    1      A      61  4 50.5
5: 2018-01-05    1      C      59  5 40.5
6: 2018-01-06    1      A      55  6 54.0
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you very much for such a comprehensive answer. I've chosen the data table option just for familiarity, and I think learning more about setting up functions would be helpful for me. Thanks again.